# Is 'grounding by chassis' achieved by the screws?

Tags: pcb, ground, grounding

Sometimes a piece of equipment uses the chassis by grounding. Is it done through those screws that fix the PCB to the case?

On a separate note, are PCB standoffs sometimes also used for this purpose? I noticed some standoffs have a PVC tubing outside with a temperature rating. That suggests current is running through it.

Comment: Plastic standoffs, and indeed any plastic components, have a temperature rating because if it melts at 50 °C you can't use it for something that goes into the engine of a car or the inside of an oven. It's not anything to do with carrying current.

Comment: @Hearth it was a metal standoff between levels of pcbs

Comment: what do you mean by "grounding" (one of the most ubiquitous and undefined terms in electrical engineering) ? then, we will be able to tell you if the chassis mounts do it or don't.

Comment: @tobalt context: "Within the power supply the GND pins are connected to PSU chassis and PE pin of the AC inlet."

Answer (score 1):

Screws and standoffs can be used as conductors either for connecting a pcba to the chassis or other elements. For example capacitors and more bulky semiconductor devices might use screws to make connections. Often a washer is used for mechanical and electrical properties.

Comment: More specifically, an "Inside tooth star lock washer"

Comment: That is a common and reasonable choice of lock washer.